# AndEngine: Missmatch getting id of Item menus on click listener

Tags: android, andengine, menuitem

Im working with AndEngine to build my Game...
Im creating menu screen with at least 4 menus items set vertically..

Item no 1, 2, and 4 working well, but have a trouble with no 3 when it(on screen) clicked the menuItem onclick listener pointing at id no 2, and also the animated sprite/image going to no 2..

here my code

menu item id

```
    private MenuScene menuChildScene;
    private final int SINGLE_GAME = 0;
    private final int MULTI_GAME = SINGLE_GAME+ 1;
    private final int HIGH_SCORE = MULTI_GAME + 1;
    private final int ABOUT = HIGH_SCORE + 1;
```

stuff creating menus item

```
private void createMenuChildScene()
    {
        menuChildScene = new MenuScene(camera);
        menuChildScene.setPosition(0,0);

        final IMenuItem opNewgame = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new SpriteMenuItem(SINGLE_GAME, resourcesManager.btnSinglegame, vbom), 1.2f, 1);
        final IMenuItem opMultiGame = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new SpriteMenuItem(MULTI_GAME, resourcesManager.btnMultiPlayergame, vbom), 1.2f, 1);
        final IMenuItem opHightScore = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new SpriteMenuItem(HIGH_SCORE, resourcesManager.btnhighscore, vbom), 1.2f, 1);
        final IMenuItem opAbout= new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new SpriteMenuItem(ABOUT, resourcesManager.btnabout, vbom), 1.2f, 1);

        menuChildScene.addMenuItem(opNewgame);
        menuChildScene.addMenuItem(opMultiGame);
        menuChildScene.addMenuItem(opHightScore);
        menuChildScene.addMenuItem(opAbout);

        menuChildScene.buildAnimations();
        menuChildScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
        opNewgame.setPosition(opNewgame.getX(), opNewgame.getY() - 25);
        opMultiGame.setPosition(opMultiGame.getX(), opNewgame.getY() - 105);
        opHightScore.setPosition(opHightScore.getX(), opMultiGame.getY() - 105);
        opAbout.setPosition(opAbout.getX(), opHightScore.getY() - 105);
        menuChildScene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

        setChildScene(menuChildScene);
    }
```

onlick handle and listerner..

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClicked(
            org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.MenuScene pMenuScene,
            IMenuItem pMenuItem, float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY) { Log.i(TAG, HIGH_SCORE +  " click : " + pMenuItem.getID());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(pMenuItem.getID()){ 
            case SINGLE_GAME:
                resourcesManager.click.play();
                SceneManager.getInstance().loadGameScene(engine);
                return true;
            case MULTI_GAME: 
                resourcesManager.click.play();
                return true;
            case HIGH_SCORE: 
                resourcesManager.click.play();
                return true;
            case ABOUT:
                resourcesManager.click.play();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Please Help wich one I have to change to make all my menus working normally..

Thanks, Best Regards

Comment: Why you use full qualified name of `MenuScene` in `onMenuItemClicked`, but not in `createMenuChildScene`?  => check your import for MenuScene to make sure it is from AndEngine or your same name class.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

From what I can tell, in SOME cases the ItemMenus respond to their original positions where they are first being placed. Hence, if you remove the setPosition from each itemMenu, and then try to click your items, it should work perfectly fine.

I've got a code which looks almost just like your :

```
targetMenuScene = new MenuScene(camera);
targetMenuScene.setPosition(500, -1000);
targetMenuScene.attachChild(targetBackground);
targetMenuScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
targetMenuScene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

xMenuItem = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new SpriteMenuItem(MENU_X,
           resourcesManager.x, vbom), 2.1f, 2f);
xMenuItem.setPosition(920, -62);
targetMenuScene.addMenuItem(xMenuItem);

... (here are many more menuItems being added....)

setChildScene(targetMenuScene);
```

This code works absolutly great.
On the other hand, I just copied this code to a different place in my program, and I'm getting the same problem just as you do!

What I did notice is, If I alternate the code to be as :

```
subLevelSelectMenu.buildAnimations();
subLevelSelectMenu.addMenuItem(levels_level1);
subLevelSelectMenu.addMenuItem(levels_level2);
subLevelSelectMenu.addMenuItem(levels_level3);
subLevelSelectMenu.addMenuItem(levels_level4);
subLevelSelectMenu.addMenuItem(levels_level5);
```

(By that I mean, first giving them their locations (positions), second using buildAnimations, and at last, adding them to the menuScene)....

It works perfect now. I dont understand why, and not sure what BuildAnimations() actually does, but I hope this will help you out a bit.

** Notice that at my first example I didn't even use BuildAnimations(). but I was only able to fix my problem at a different part of my game with it.

If anyone else can share some information regarding this problem, please do so.

**EDIT:**

after trying some other stuff out, I simple used

```
subLevelSelectMenu.clearTouchAreas();
```

before adding all the menu items... and hey, that worked!

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check the positioning of the menu items again. Normally, you don't have to set their positions, they are positioned one after another vertically. I think 2 of your menu items are overlapping with each other. Try not to set positions for the menu items. They will be set automatically.